# Wysiwyg editor with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wysiwyg

I am using Rails 4.2.5 & Ruby 2.3.
I am trying to use "wysiwyg-rails" gem(https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-rails) for wsyiwyg editor. I have added the gem to Gemfile & have done bundle install. It works. But when I start the server, it gives me the below error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/skylight-1.0.0/lib/skylight/probes.rb:81:in `require': cannot load such file -- font-awesome-rails (LoadError)
```

Don't know from where the font-awesome-rails is coming from. It is not used anywhere.
I have added all the dependencies

1. Added the gem: gem 'font-awesome-sass'
2. Have added the dependency in application css & js files.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `font-awesome-sass` is dependency of `wysiwyg-rails`, you shouldn't need to declare it, have you executed `bundle install`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the font awesome rails gem is actually here: https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails

Add to gemfile, bundle install, then In your application.css, include the css file:

```
/*
 *= require font-awesome
 */
```